# Why does PyCharm has different output in 'Run' and 'Debug'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, set

I have a problem with set(). This code has different output in 'Run' and in 'Debug'.

```
n = set(input()) #input - 3490
m = set(input()) #input - 9340
if n == m:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Run - False, Debug - True.
I can't understand why this is happened. Please help
Python 3.10

Comment: It's not possible, you're probably running one program and debugging another - PyCharm is known as a very confusing IDE for running programs until you get used to it.

Note that running with the Play button you are actually running the program and running with the bug icon you are debugging - these are 2 different things

Comment: I've just created new project and rechecked this. Difference still exists. I've got only one interpreter 3.10, one project and one .py file in project.

Comment: It is interesting - But if I use this, run and debug show 'True': n = set('3490') 
m = set('9340') 
if n == m:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

Comment: I ran your code with numerous values in the latest version of PyCharm (2022.1.1 build #PY-221.5591.52). The results are same in both the execution and debugging processes so please provide screenshots from the "Run" and the "Debug" tabs of your PyCharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a regression in PyCharm 2022.1.1. It handles STDIN incorrectly during the Run hence the difference. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call

Update to [2022.1.2 RC (release candidate)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/PY-A-23004355) where the problem is resolved